# Is speed improvement to be expected from rooting/modding a Samsung Galaxy Player 4.2 YP-GI1

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-nexus, performance

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Player 4.2 YP-GI1 lying around and would like to use it either as a media player or a media center remote. However even after a factory reset the device or the UI reacts like a slug. There is some bloatware on it some of which can apparently not be deactivated.
Will rooting and throwing something like the Ethereal ROM on it (as listed here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1720457 ) considerably improve its performance?

I am asking because I tried SuperOneClick and it does not work. I guess it is not worth the time and effort if I can not expect better performance. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaining ROOT Access will not impact performance at all...

It is what you do to Tweak the performance After Gaining Root that will have a drastic effect on performance..

But Always Remember that Performance and Power Consumption come Hand in Hand..

The Higher the Performance m, The quicker the power drain ... The Sloweemr the Performance The Slower the Drain...

It is why many people UnderClock their devices, rather than OverClock...

That being said, Yes you can expect some Performance enhancements with the correct Tweaks....

For example, 
Using a Popular Benchmark software, i was able to get a performance increase of about 500% ..
 .
The initial device at Factor specifications gave me 1/ 5th of the Benchmark from a Tweaked device...

The most effective twaeks are adding difference props inside the Build.prop file under /system 
 .Of course /system is not available to edit without Root Access.

---

---

To have a less slugish experience Without using root access, i suggest the following tweaks.

- Remove BloatWare

  - Apps you don't ever plan to use.
- Disable Apps that Can not be removed
- Open Storage Settings, and Click on Caches

  - Clear your App Caches
- Clear your Browser Cookies

  - This one is a bit strange, but it works on many device's.
- Disable Animations in Development Options

  - Android displays Animations every single time you open or close something, this can Add up to 4 years of someone's life just waiting for Animations, it takes a lot of resources to load the animations and that drastically effects battery life and performance.

I've added some example screenshots of disabling Animations below.

[image: 2]

---

[image: 1]

---

[image: 3]

---

[image: 4]

---

### [image: 5]

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and time. Of course I did not expect an improvement from rooting in itself. My hope is that a custom ROM (or the changes you suggest) make the device usable = less sluggish. Power consumption is already a problem, as even a (supposedly) new battery I bought will be drained within less than a day even if I do not touch/use the thing at all. But as a media player it will be used stationary so power consumption won't be a major problem. However, with SuperOneClick failing I currently have no hope at all.

Comment: Yes you can make many speed improvements after you have gained access to RW the system, you can remove the BloatWare, that in itself will significantly improve performance..  For a nice trick to improve User Interface performance is to Turn OFF Animations all together... You need to enable development options to get access to the Animation settings .... To enable Development Options, go into your settings application and look for the About section, when you find About, ooen it and Tap on Build Number 7 Times ...

Comment: Ill update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No luck on the Developer options front, though: This is still Android 2.3.6 and activating USB debugging is more or less all I can do.

Comment: Android 2.3.6 is very easy to gain root access using just an application on the device itself.